# QGIS Valmiera, Labels only show for part of polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling

Using 2.2.0-Valmiera on Ubuntu 13.10

I have for Croatia 21 Counties as polygons.
Labels show only for 12 counties: here I see that no labels are shown for multipart features.
So I checked "Show labels for multipart features": No change
I unchecked "Discourage labels from covering features: No change

I tried a layer with all Municipalities cca 500 polygons.
Labels show for most polygons but not all. All multipart polygons failed to show labels.

Then I found out that this behaviour of is dependent of the scaling. At 1:25000 all labels show, also on multipart but at 1:50.000 part of the labels are not shown.
I controlled:
- Scale based visibility : unchecked so okay
- Topology: No errors
- Geometry validity: no errors

Has anyone seen this behaviour and perhaps know a solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This is a known issue](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9655) for the QGIS 2.2 release. It has recently been fixed, but not backported to 2.2 release, yet. However, you can temporarily work around the issue by turning **Simplify geometry** to **OFF** for the layer (under Rendering in Vector Layer Properties).

If that does not fix your issue, then you may have a number of polygons with invalid geometry. Try running the *Vector -> Geometry tools -> Check geometry validity* command in the main menu. Invalid geometries may be rendered, but not necessarily labeled, so you would need to fix your data.

You can try to fix any invalid geometry using the [Processing LWGEOM Provider plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processinglwgeomprovider/), which has a Make Valid command. Otherwise, you may have to manually fix problematic polygons.

Comment: Turning Simplify geometry to OFF worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the labelling icon, you have a `Rendering` tab at the bottom.

There you can check `Show all labels for this layer`

And in the `Feature Options` below you can also check or uncheck some more options.

Comment: I have done that and still the same behaviour.... Interesting is that when I press Toggle Editing for the layer the label appears. Also when the scale is 1:25000 and below.

Comment: I also tried changing the Text from a point size to map units but still same.